# jvectormaps Changing div onRegionClick

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

what i have is 3 divs each with their own ID's in a class. In a CSS file i have made the class "display:none;".

```
<div class="stat">
<div id="one"> <p>one</p> </div>
<div id="two"> <p>two</p> </div>
<div id="three"> <p>three</p> </div>
</div>
```

What i want is to have the map be able to change the display on a specific div everytime i click a state. For example, everytime i click state A, div one will appear, if i click state B, div two will appear where Div A was.

fiddle link if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/mrvvuh1n/

cheers

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle link as I am not able to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late answer, but I hope this will help someone.

If it doesn't need to be templated, i suggest this solution with JQuery:

```
$('path[data-code="#"]').click(function(){
    $('#one').css('display', 'block');
    $('#two').css('display', 'hidden'); //something like that, for example
});
```

where instead of # will be the data-code of the state that you need, you can find it just by looking in the source code.

And, of course, "display: none;" in the CSS file need to be applied to the blocks with ids (one, two, three), not to the class "stat".

Not sure about the code, didn't check if there are any syntax errors. Feel free to write so i doublecheck it.